# A way to force a suite of test to fail once a step is failed in Cypress?

Tags: cypress

is there any way to make a testSuite Fail once one of step test is failed .

In other words , force to fail suiteTest once a step is failed

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to force fail a test in Cypress.io](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56993461/how-to-force-fail-a-test-in-cypress-io)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Cypress: interrupt all tests on first failure](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61661932/cypress-interrupt-all-tests-on-first-failure)

Answer (score 0):

It seems like this feature was introduced, but it requires paid version of Cypress (Business Plan). Otherwise you might need to do some hacking in command.js, check out this link might be helpful [Stackoverflow Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61661932/cypress-interrupt-all-tests-on-first-failure)

Comment: This is not what he was asking 
this feature will stop all the specs from running in case of one spec fails 
but the question was to fail tests belong to that case it self